# Embedded Software Programming Resources (Microcontrollers, EPROM)

Tags: embedded

Does anyone know any good online embedded software programming with C or assembler
resources? Google's not really helping out with its search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microchip](http://www.microchip.com) has free (student version) compilers, and lots of app notes.

[Embedded System Programming](http://www.embedded.com/) magazine/website has articles, forums, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Embedded.com](http://Embedded.com) as well as Jack Ganssle's collection of [articles](http://www.ganssle.com/articles.htm). Well worth the read. [EmbeddedRelated.com](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/) is also a good resource with access to various newsgroups archives.

To get familiar with a microcontroller it is always helpful to grab a datasheet, e.g. the Freescale S12X offers a wide variety of functionality (from CAN, SCI etc.). Search Freescale's [website](http://www.freescale.com) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck if you choose one of the microcontroller families.
In my view AVR is a good point to start, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412444/recommendations-for-embbededrealtime-development-training#412726).

I also recommend [Embedded.com](http://www.embedded.com).

**Edit:** If you speak German then check out [mikrocontroller.net](http://www.mikrocontroller.net).